# How to detect when no cell is selected while using Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)?

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

In my Sub I'm using below code to obtain user selected range.

```vb
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

It works fine as long as user selects some cells/range. However whenever macro is called without selecting any cells, rng overflows and application freezes. Is there any way to detect if user hasn't selected any cells and exit safely?.

Comment: Why not use an `Application.InputBox` to prompt the user to select a range? You can use `.SpecialCells` with the result, instead of relying on `Selection`.

Comment: Your code fails on the line `Set rng =`? I just hid the row that I had selected (to make it 'not visible') in a test case, then tried your code and it executed instantly. I added `Msgbox Rng.Address` and it returned `$2:$1048576`, so sure you would have a large range if the selection was hidden, but I didn't crash though. I feel like we are missing some important code here.

Comment: I second @K.Dᴀᴠɪs. Hiding some cells, and then having only *one* visible cell selected, selects all the visible cells in the sheet, all the way to the last row/column. You might also want to test if `Selection.CountLarge > 1`, after testing that `Selection` is a `Range`.

Answer (score 1):

Is a range selected?

```
If TypeOf Selection is Range Then
```

Does the selected range have visible cells?

```vb
On Error Resume Next 'ignore error if there are no visible cells in the selected range
Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error Goto 0      'stop ignoring errors

If Not rng Is Nothing then
   'do something with rng
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Final Solution that I ended Up Using

Check if selection is a range and CountLarge greater than 1 ; Use ErrorHandler to deal with cases where no visible cell is selected.

```vb
If TypeOf Selection Is Range And Selection.CountLarge > 1 Then
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
'other bits of code
Else
ErrorHandler: 
'Inform user that macro only works with 2 or more visible cells selected
End If
```

Credits to @[BigBen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9245853/bigben) for the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67795301/how-to-detect-when-no-cell-is-selected-while-using-selection-specialcellsxlcell/67795467#comment119831493_67795301) and @[Tim Willams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/478884/tim-williams)'s [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67795467/15690728)

Comment: Note that in VBA `And` doesn't short-circuit, so both parts of that `If` will be evaluated, and you'll get an error if `Selection` is not a range.